# Trying to bind Ctrl-<right> to forward-word in emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, key-bindings

I'm on Mac OS 10.12.3 (Sierra), using Gnu Emacs 25.1 (9.0).  I've been an Emacs user for a long time, but (unfortunately) not a Lisp programmer.  I have a .emacs file I've carried around for a long time that sets up customizations that I've scraped from here and there.

Having just set up on a new system, switching from Aquamacs to Gnu Emacs, I have one remaining thing I'm trying to set up, namely getting the "forward-word" and "backward-word" commands to map to Ctrl-<right> and Ctrl-<left>, respectively.

I've tried:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<right>") 'forward-word)
```

and

```
(global-set-key (quote [C-right]) (quote forward-word))
```

and neither works.  The "meta" key has been mapped to the Apple command key, which I think is why this doesn't work:

```
(global-set-key "\M-[1;5C"    'forward-word)
```

Can anyone please help?  If you want to flame me for not knowing Lisp first, that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

- Ask Emacs how to describe the key sequence
- Use what it tells you with `kbd`

`C-h k` followed by Ctrl-<right> tells me `<C-right>` and therefore I would use `(kbd "<C-right>")`

Comment: Ok, I tried: (global-set-key (kbd "<C-right>") (quote forward-word)), which didn't seem to do anything.  I also tried to replicate what you did C-h k, but when I do that and type Ctrl-right, nothing happens.  Finally I hit enter, and it describes what enter does.  ??

Comment: @M.Hearne Emacs probably isn't getting the key presses then.  I'm not familiar with MacOS so I can't really help you further, other than to say this is a function of the GUI/terminal you're using.  Maybe Aquamacs was doing something vanilla GNU Emacs isn't to get that keypress.

Comment: I just figured it out - those key combinations were being taken by the OS, so once I turned that off, it works as expected.  New laptop, so having to re-figure out all of my settings, system or otherwise.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your Mac or Iterm may absorb your input combinations especially when they have system keys. On Mac, open `settings -> keyboard -> Shortcuts` and ensure you don't have overrides in that list. If you run console version of Emacs, check your Iterm settings too.

Comment: If you are having trouble defining key bindings in Emacs for MacOS, this is a good place to start.